# SQLite3 Formatting Issue with Parameters - Updating an existing value by adding another value

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently in the process of learning how to use the sqlite3 module inside Python. I'm trying to write code that will update a value from a column in sqlite by adding a new value to an existing value, but I'm running into formatting issues that I don't know how to fix...

I know that the basic syntax for doing this (as far as I'm aware) is the following:

```py
sql_statement = "UPDATE table 
                 SET column_name = column_name + new_value 
                 WHERE condition;"
```

The issue I'm running into is that I'm trying to insert the column name using dictionary parameters from python. This is where the problem is occuring in my code:

```py
muscle = 'Lats'
num_sets = 5
week_num = 40

sql_statement = f"UPDATE WeeklyMuscleSets 
                 SET {muscle} = (:muscle) + (:num_sets) 
                 WHERE WeekID = (:week_num);"

parameters = {'muscle':muscle,'num_sets':num_sets,'week_num':week_num}

c.execute(sql_statement,parameters)
```

The code runs just fine, but instead of adding to the existing value in the table it is replacing it. I did some testing, and when I manually enter the value for the "muscle" variable, it updates just fine.

```py
muscle = 'Lats'
num_sets = 5
week_num = 40

sql_statement = f"UPDATE WeeklyMuscleSets 
                 SET {muscle} = Lats + (:num_sets) 
                 WHERE WeekID = (:week_num);"

parameters = {'num_sets':num_sets,'week_num':week_num}

c.execute(sql_statement,parameters)
```

It also worked when I used f-string formatting for the muscle variable, however I know that is bad practice and leaves the code vulnerable to injection attacks.

For some reason when I use the parameters it doesn't add the new value to the existing one and instead replaces it, and I'm at a loss as to why. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Table and column names have to be directly present in the statement; they can't be bound as parameters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019599/sqlite-why-cant-parameters-be-used-to-set-an-identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is parameterized query. Then the query and values are sent to the DBMS engin separately and the DBMS use the values in the **parsed** query. Then the parsed query stored and used again so the performance improved and SQL injection can not be happened.

If you want to add `num_sets` to the current value of `muscle` you must use `muscle + :num_sets` :

```py
num_sets = 5
week_num = 40

sql_statement = f"UPDATE WeeklyMuscleSets 
                 SET muscle = muscle + :num_sets
                 WHERE WeekID = :week_num;"

parameters = {'num_sets':num_sets,'week_num':week_num}

c.execute(sql_statement,parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So basically it's like what Shawn said in that I cannot use parameters for table or column names? So using f-string formatting is acceptable for retrieving the column name and is not bad practice?

Comment: @BrandonM Yes Shawn is right. It is not bad practice and in fact it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code runs fine?  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31277027/3324095) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8841488/3324095), it isn't possible to use named placeholders for table names or column names.  You are trying to use a named placeholder for a column so I would expect an exception to be raised.

Two ways around the problem spring to mind:

1. Use string {formatting}.  As you point out, this has the downside of allowing SQL injection attacks.  However, it is possible to sanitise data from the user.  If security is that much of a concern, you should probably be using some kind of ORM instead of raw SQL.
2. Re-structure your table so that it looks more like:

   ```
   create WeeklyMuscleSets (
       muscle varchar,
       number_of_sets number,
       week number
   )
   ```

   and your query to look more like this:

   ```
   update WeeklyMuscleSets 
   set number_of_sets = number_of_sets + :extra_sets
   where muscle = :muscle
   ```

Comment: Basically, when I tried to use a named placeholder for the column name it would raise a syntax error. When ordered like this and using an f-string: {muscle} = (:muscle) + (:num_sets) didn't raise any error, but obviously any existing value for the muscle was being ignored when the code ran. Thank you for your reply and suggestion!